# Why does it throw OOM?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

Here is the server1's Heap memory info

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 157286400 (150.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 157286400 (150.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 19922944 (19.0MB)
   used     = 19911792 (18.989364624023438MB)
   free     = 11152 (0.0106353759765625MB)
   99.94402433696546% used
From Space:
   capacity = 12517376 (11.9375MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 12517376 (11.9375MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 13303808 (12.6875MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 13303808 (12.6875MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 715849728 (682.6875MB)
   used     = 715848480 (682.6863098144531MB)
   free     = 1248 (0.001190185546875MB)
   99.99982566173442% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 157286400 (150.0MB)
   used     = 79364440 (75.68782806396484MB)
   free     = 77921960 (74.31217193603516MB)
   50.45855204264323% used
```

I allocate 1024M memory to the JVM Heap,but the JVM is not use up the memory when it OOM

I have another server,the next is the server's heap memory info when it was OOM

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 157286400 (150.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 157286400 (150.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 119341056 (113.8125MB)
   used     = 119253176 (113.72869110107422MB)
   free     = 87880 (0.08380889892578125MB)
   99.92636230736889% used
From Space:
   capacity = 111869952 (106.6875MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 111869952 (106.6875MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 111149056 (106.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 111149056 (106.0MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 715849728 (682.6875MB)
   used     = 715849720 (682.6874923706055MB)
   free     = 8 (7.62939453125E-6MB)
   99.99999888244702% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 157286400 (150.0MB)
   used     = 110605624 (105.48174285888672MB)
   free     = 46680776 (44.51825714111328MB)
   70.32116190592448% used
```

this server looks simple normal,the memory is real not enough

Who can provide a clear explanation of the server1 OOM

Comment: In both cases Eden and OldGen are full so I guess that's the cause of OOM. However, the first server has less NewGen capacity. What JVM settings do you use for server-1? Did you try to play with NewRatio and SurvivorRatio?

Comment: I do not change the NewRatio and SurvivorRatio, as you see the two server has same NewRatio and SurvivorRatio by default.

Answer (score 1):

As Vladimir said - You have OldGen full, you should check NewRatio and Survivor ratio. You can also start Your application with gc logs, and analyze it in external tool, for example: http://gceasy.io (Free) or JClarity Censum (Paid)

Enable gc logs by providing flags:
 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:gc.log

Comment: thank you ,I don't save the gc logs on this time, so cann't analyze. I will try it on next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `MinHeapFreeRatio = 40` which means the GC should kick around this time.  Ideally your tenured space should be less than this percentage full.

The old gen appears to be 682 MB which means it should really be at least 682/0.4 or 1700 MB (which is more than your total), but I suspect it really needs to much higher if the application was allowed to run longer.

If this figure is surprising, I suggest you use your memory profiler to see if you have a memory leak or you can reduce memory consumption.